# Asciidoctor gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, asciidoctor

Is there a way to exlude a folder from asciidoctor's gradle plugin so that it doesn't search for .adoc's in it.

Here is what i have for now in my build.gradle:

```
asciidoctor {
    resources {
        from(sourceDir) {
            include 'img/**'
        }
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
asciidoctor {
    resources {
        from(sourceDir) {
            include 'img/**'
            exclude 'extensions/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried does exactly what you asked it to. You told the plugin that it should not search for **resources** in the directory `extensions`. This does not affect the **sources** that are transformed. And actually, it has no effect, as only the `img` folder is included in the first place.

What you need instead is this:

```
asciidoctor {
    sources {
        exclude 'extensions/**'
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I added this piece of code in asciidocotor it is now trying to parse my images in img folder and crashing.

Comment: This is the error: Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) asciidoctor: FAILED: C:/projects/my_project/src/main/asciidoc/img/image.png: Failed to parse source, invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Comment: Well, then maybe also add an include, or also exclude the images folder or something like that. I don't use that plugin, I just had a look at its documentation.

Comment: I've tried all those but I'll find something, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vampire the folder was correctly excluded however the resource folder wasn't copied anymore and is apperently a known bug. This is the workaround I used to make it work how I intended to:

```
asciidoctor {
    sources {
        exclude 'extensions/**'
        exclude 'generated/*.txt'
        exclude 'img/**'
    }
}
task copyResources(type: Copy) {
    from ("src/main/asciidoc/img") {
        include '**'
    }
    into("${buildDir}/asciidoc/html5/img")
}

asciidoctor.dependsOn(copyResources)
```